# fadeIn doesn't work in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

It's the simplest think on earth but it doesn't work!! fadeIn function doesn't work in **IE9**?
 here is a demo: http://sergejpopov.com/test.htm

Any ideas? I found this: http://www.kevinleary.net/wp-samples/ie-fade-problems.php but couldn't figure out how they fixed it.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".a").click(function () {
                $(".b").fadeIn("500");
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .b{ display:none; background-color:#fff;}
</style>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="a" >aaa</a>
    <p class="b">bbb</p>
```

**EDIT:**

weird but fadeOut is working without any issues..

Comment: Why do you still use that ugly `javascript:void(0)`? Just `return false;` in the click function

Comment: Also you don't need to put quotes around `500`

Comment: @PeeHaa, thanks for pointing but this doesn't help..

Comment: Are you sure it works when I test it using IE9

Comment: @PeeHaa, yep, I just get this: http://sergejpopov.com/Capture.JPG

Comment: Strange it works in my end: http://pieterhordijk.com/sandbox/strange.png IE 9.0.8112.16421 . Are you sure JS is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what i have figured out is that it breaks in IE9 if the display property set to none; and the only way to make it work is instead of setting display:none; to hide(); it on page load..

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".b").hide();
            $(".a").click(function () {
                $(".b").fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            });
            $(".c").click(function () {
                $(".d").fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The duration should be an integer, try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".a").click(function () {
                $(".b").fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
```

Comment: updated, still same thing: http://sergejpopov.com/test.htm , it works in every other browser but not in IE9..

Comment: Upgrade Jquery to 1.6+ if you are using older version. There are few issues with Jquery in IE9

Comment: updated - no luck, weird but fadeOut function is working fine.

Comment: fadeIn should also work if you have upgraded to 1.6.1 or 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a").click(function () {
        $(".b").fadeIn(500);

        return false;
    });
});

<a href="#" class="a" >aaa</a>
<p class="b">bbb</p>
```